# mysql multiple where and inner join query combination

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm a little lost as how to run two mysql queries as one(return one result set to be sorted etc).

I understand how to do multiple JOINS but need to combine the below which is more than just a multiple join - it would include a multiple where etc.

1st query

```
     sql = "SELECT s.id, s.song_name
           FROM `songs` as s
           INNER JOIN `artists` as a ON s.artist_id = a.id
           WHERE ((`a`.id = #{search}))"
```

2nd query

```
   sql = "SELECT s.id, s.song_name
      FROM `songs` as s
      INNER JOIN `similarments` as si ON s.artist_id = si.artist_id
      WHERE ((`si`.similar_id = #{search}))"
```

And then run both queries at once so I can ORDER them etc.
Or combine them as one big query (maybe put an OR somewhere)?

Thanks!

Comment: LEFT JOIN to both tables in a single query from SONGs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to run two queries and combine the results is to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) (or `UNION ALL` if you don't wish to remove duplicates). In your case it would look like this:

```
(
    SELECT s.id, s.song_name
    FROM `songs` as s
    INNER JOIN `artists` as a ON s.artist_id = a.id
    WHERE ((`a`.id = #{search}))
)
UNION
(
    SELECT s.id, s.song_name
    FROM `songs` as s
    INNER JOIN `similarments` as si ON s.artist_id = si.artist_id
    WHERE ((`si`.similar_id = #{search}))
)
ORDER BY ....
```